# How to get parameter values of a callback function?

Tags: python, function, parameters, callback

I am trying to make call for a callback function in python.
I have a dll present at a path say 'dllpath'.
This dll have a callback function stated below:

Function prototype:
ULONG SetByteTotalsCallback(tFNByteTotals pCallback,BYTE interval);

Parameter discription:
tFNByteTotals pCallback: mode-IN, Callback function pointer 
BYTE interval:mode-IN,  Interval in seconds

Callback Prototype:
void ByteTotalsCallback(ULONGLONG txTotalBytes, ULONGLONG rxTotalBytes );

I want to call the function SetByteTotalsCallback and I want to print the values of txTotalBytes and rxTotalBytes.

I tried with following code:

```
from ctypes import *
filepath = r"<path to dll>"
gdll = WinDLL(filepath)
tx = c_longlong
rx = c_longlong
pCallback = CFUNCTYPE(tx, rx)
def ByteTotalsCallback(t, r):
    try:
        print 'Printing tx and rx: '
        #print 'Transmitted bytes: ',t[0]
        #print 'Received bytes: ',r[0]
        #return 0
    except:
        print 'Error...'

byteTotal_func =pCallback(ByteTotalsCallback)
SetByteTotalsCallback = gdll.SetByteTotalsCallback
try:
    print 'Return of SetByteTotals:     ',SetByteTotalsCallback(pCallback(ByteTotalsCallback), c_byte(128))

except:
    print 'Error found: '
```

After executing the above code, I observe that the function ByteTotalsCallback is not getting called but SetByteTotalsCallback(pCallback(ByteTotalsCallback), c_byte(128))
got called and returned back successfully.

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Geet

Comment: The standard ctypes documentation describes how to create Python callback functions that can be passed to C. Do you have a specific question beyond what the standard documentation provides?

Comment: The code helps, thanks. I see you setting the callback and it looks correct. Is anything actually calling it though? Typically the function to set the callback function doesn't actually call it, it just remembers it for later.

Comment: I want to retrieve values from the parameters of the callback function. In the above example, I want the values of txTotalbytes and rxTotalbytes

Comment: Indeed, however, your callback function needs to be executed before you can get any parameters. How is your callback function called once you've set it? Are you certain the DLL is even trying to call your callback function?

Comment: Hi Rakis, thats right, the dll calls the callback function and I want the values of the parameters of the callback function called by the dll. Can you help me for this?

Comment: Your code looks correct, except the callback parameters won't be tuples. Try changing the print statement in your callback function to `print "callback args: ", t, r` and see what happens.